# How to set height and width of object tag so that no scrollbars appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a webpage inside a div using object tag of html. I have tried loading it inside a div but since the host name of that webpage differes, it gives CORS error.

Also tried iframe but it requires `scrolling='no'` to remove scrollbars. So, I decided to use object tag after referring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object. I am able to remove the scroll bars if I specify fixed height and width in pixels. However, I want to decide this dynamically based on screen resolution to avaoid scrollbars appearing for any devices/browsers.

How can I achieve this? Below is my code snippet.

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <!--  Main content goes here -->
    <object type="text/html" data="<%=url%>" style="overflow: auto;" align="middle" standby="Loading ..." id="py-content"> </object>
</div>
```

I really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried setting the height and width to `em` and checking it?

Comment: A fiddle would be helpfull

Comment: @ Dreamwalker - As per my understanding, em is to set font-size. I am trying to set div size automatically. So, my assumption was to do it using jquery on page load.

Comment: So, this issue is resolved by populating contents inside a div using jquery load() and enabling cross-origin request by adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at server side. The options considered before were: 1) iframe, 2) object 3) div. The third option worked properly and after modifying appropriate css, I was able to eliminate unwanted scroll-bars. The first and second options of using iframe or object tags, both required setting the height and width of corresponding html elements, and that was causing issue in different devices/browsers.